# Multiple Torahs given at Sinai - apparently when Moshe established the 13 Torahs they had different spellings/minhagim?

Tags: mitzvah, moshe-rabbeinu

Multiple Torahs given at Sinai - apparently when Moshe established the 13 Torahs they had different spellings/minhagim? Please can someone provide a source regarding different spellings

Comment: They were all the same.

Comment: We need some sources so we can discuss this.

Comment: You’re probably thinking of the Midrash that says that Moshe wrote 13 scrolls. One they put in the Aron Hakodesh, and the other 12 he gave one to each tribe. However, all Torahs were identical

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please make sure to give all background in your question incl. quoting relevant sources, there is a lot of space in that question box; use it! Great to have you learn with us!